# C++ get data from double pointer

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ area and faced with double pointers. The question is how to set `x=5` in function `test`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _DoublePointer
{
    int x;
    int y;
} DoublePointer;

void test(_DoublePointer** pointer)
{

}

void main()
{
    _DoublePointer* pointer = new _DoublePointer;
    _DoublePointer** doublePointer = &pointer;
    test(doublePointer);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_DoublePointer`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the way to do that is

```
(*pointer)->x = 5;
```